# current value of x for vector2 game object

Tags: unity, 2d

I just need to push my game object in y direction not in of its x position,I need to assign it a new position but unable to access its current x position value so that can make it fix on its x position... please help

I tried this:

> ```
> Vector2 curScreenPoint = new Vector2 (need the current x position of game object , Input.mousePosition.y);
> ```

```
Vector2 curScreenPoint = new Vector2 (0, Input.mousePosition.y);
     Vector2 curPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (curScreenPoint);
    transform.position = curPosition;
```

---

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish based on your code.
Possibly you are not familiar with the MonoBehaviour object type.

Have you tried something like this:

```
Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (Input.mousePosition);
transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, mousePos.y);
```

Comment: actually i have to move an object only in y position not in x,i want to assign the current value of x position while all the movements..

Comment: @SantoshYadav Updated code above.

Comment: still not working... please have a look on edited problem scenario

Comment: @SantoshYadav Updated code again.

Comment: already tried this before but not getting desired functionality,both slider comes to same position...

Comment: Is this script attached to your Paddle?

Comment: yes it is attached

Comment: My code checks out, should work.  Not sure why it is not.  if you put this code in your Update function, and have it attached to your paddle, it should retain its default X axis position, and follow the mouse along its Y axis.